# -ing phrase tag-line?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, present-participles, ing

I'm currently rebuilding a website for a client.  On their website, the tag-line reads

> "Specializing in Manufactured Housing Communities"

Is this grammatically correct? In my opinion,

> "Specialists in Manufactured Housing Communities"

sounds better.  If it is grammatically correct, however, I'll leave it how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me **specializing in** manufactured housing (as in some field of activity) sounds fine. Specializing in communities sounds a little bit weird to me. But as @TrevorD pointed there's nothing wrong with using **specialists in**. There are many results on Google saying something like

> 'Specialists in General Surgery' (http://sgsmn.com)
>
> 'Association of Consultants and Specialists in Restorative Dentistry' (http://www.restdent.org.uk)

Comment: They are a real estate firm. If that makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Specializing in sounds better.

Unless the specialists are actually inside the manufactured housing community.

Answer (score 0):

To my British ear, either sounds fine, but I would say that **Specialists in** is probably more common in the UK. It reads in the sense of:

> [We are] **Specialists in** [a particular trade, area of work, field of activity, etc.]

There is absolutely no implication (as suggested in another answer) that "the specialists are actually inside the ... community".